# How to show or hide properties dynamically in the PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I am using a PropertyGrid for configuring objects. I need to be able to hide or show some properties depending on the values of other properties. How this can be achieved? I know about Browsable attribute, but it only works at a compile time.

Comment: I have found the following example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/DynPropGrid.aspx You can include conditions what to show and what to hide in you code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look into the [`ICustomTypeDescriptor` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx).

Further informations on how to use it can be found in this article:

- [Bending the .NET PropertyGrid to Your Will](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/bending_property.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. The article on the codeproject seems to be a very nice one.

Comment: Code sample please

Answer (score -2):

Check this link [Changing Browsable Property Attribute dynamically](http://www.dotnetstuffs.com/topic/how-to-show-hide-properties-dynamically-in-propertygrid/).A sample method is given.
Using Reflection access the Property and set its browsable property to true or false.