# Programmatically filter custom properties

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, propertygrid

I have an existing custom control library with controls which may contain properties: HeaderStyle, ModalStyle, Collapsable, etc...

In the user interface the program is currently displaying a categorized list of these properties.  I am trying to update this code to hide properties they dont normally use.  I have a list of properties to hide/show based on button click but I am not sure how I can hide these fields programmatically.

I would like to retain any values entered into the fields before hiding and re-display the values if the fields are shown again.

Here is a property that current exists but would like to be hidden/shown on toggle.

```
/// <summary>ModalStyle property for control</summary>
[XmlAttribute]
[DefaultValue(Utility.Common.Enumerations.ModalStyle.None)]
[Category(PropertyCategories.Rendering)]
[Description("Modal dialog style")]
public ModalStyle? ModalStyle
{
get { return control.ModalStyleActive; }
set { control.ModalStyle = value; }
}
```

My original though was to do some variant on #if DEBUG but use my own Conditional however I was unable to find a way to change my conditionals via button/toggle.

Can anyone please help with a solution to my problem?  I have 20-30 controls with 20 to 30 properties that would like to be filtered.

Comment: How are you displaying the properties? That code will need to hide some of them, you shouldn't modify the original object.

Comment: I am using a winForms:PropertyGrid.

Comment: Perhaps the solution lies down the path of [Browsable]?  Is it possible to toggle [Browsable] on and off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions that, while they may not give you the exact functionality desired, will keep your solution much more straight forward.

First:
Since you are the library developer you should just decide what properties you want other developers to have access to though the IDE properties window. If a property is seldom used or not very useful through the IDE then just place the [Browsable(false)] attribute on it.

Second:
If you really want all properties to be visible in the IDE properties window, but want to give individuals a way of hiding the more advanced (or less used) ones, just throw them all in an 'Advanced' category. The user can then simply collapse that category and forget about them.

Also: Take a look at Oliver's answer to this question:
[[how-to-show-or-hide-properties-dynamically-in-the-propertygrid]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831878/how-to-show-or-hide-properties-dynamically-in-the-propertygrid)

Comment: I am hopeful of the link referencing a link and am currently reading into it.

Comment: Olivers answer was a good one.  His PropertyBag class really hit me in the face.  I can very easily save user settings of which fields they like in a user settings screen.  Then just pulling only those properties from the master list is simple.  One problem I am having is all properties included this way are showing up as read only...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve.

When you use Attributes, those are static to the class. So, in your case, when you toggle a show/hide on an object, it's on an instance of the object. Also, you cannot change an attribute value at run-time.

Maybe you should try an alternate solution like creating a global

```
map<pair<type of object, property name>, is shown>
```

and update that accordingly from your editor.

And if you want to use something like a property grid, you will have a problem since it won't check your map, but it can be fixed. You could create a new class at run-time and make it a proxy to your current instance. (check on the net how to achieve that, but it's quite simple. There are 2 possibilities: compile from a string or use the ILGenerator.

Hope this help.